# How can I show different category list for different theme?

Tags: magento-1.7, category, theme

I have two themes for a single store view...(**desktop and iphone**)
I have created some subcategories under the root category for my store. Let's say those are :

1. categoryone
2. categorytwo
3. categorythree
4. categoryfour

Now I **want to show only the first 3 categories**(1, 2, 3) **in the iphone** theme..
By default it is showing all of them..  But I don't want to show the last one in the iphone theme only.

This is the code for category listing..

```
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_childCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
    ->addAttributeToFilter("parent_id", $_category->getId());  
 <section class="category-list">
    <ul class="ulPrdCatgAthome prmCatList">
        <?php foreach ($_childCats as $category) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php
                if ($category->getThumbnailUrl()) {
                    $imgPath = $category->getThumbnailUrl();
                } else {
                    $imgPath = $this->getSkinUrl("images/img_old/np_product_main.gif");
                }
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl($category); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>">
                    <span class="img1"><span><img src="<?php echo $imgPath; ?>" alt="" /></span></span>
                    <span class="mobile_arrow"><?php echo truncateHtml($category->getName(), 40, '...', false, true); ?></span>
                    <span class="rhtindcator"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/custom/mobile-arrow-rht.png') ?>" width="100%" alt="" /></span>
                </a>
            </li>
<?php } ?>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Is there any way to **separate categories as per the theme** for a single store view ?
Could anyone, **please suggest how to do this** ?

Comment: Have you tried with  different website instead of store view . Use different   root category

Comment: I have to create in the single website and in the same store view.

Answer (score 0):

- First, detect user agent where categories are being rendered (navigation menu, filters)
- Second, skip the category if the user agent is iPhone.
- Use this function to detect user agent:

  ```
  function isIpad()
  {

      $isiPad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');

      $is_andriod = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android');

      $iPhone = (bool)stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone');


      if($isiPad){

          return "isiPad";

          }

      if($iPhone){

          return "iPhone";

      }

      if($is_andriod){

          return "is_andriod";

          }

      else {

          return false;
      }

  }
  ```
- Usage: the function will return either '**iPhone**' if useragent is iPhone. Enjoy :)

Comment: But how can I assign each category to a theme ?

Comment: In this way when I see in a mobile device, then for each category it will return mobile user agent and all the categories will be displayed.

Comment: Go to **Catalog->Manage Categories**. Then select your category and choose tab **Custom Design -> Custom Design** dropdown, then select whichever theme you want to display on the selected category.

Comment: Custom Design dropdown will list all the themes available inside you **app/design/frontend/default or base** directory

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Catalog** -> **Manage Categories** and choose the category you want to assign different design.
Then Choose tab **Custom Design** -> **Custom Design dropdown** select the template you wish to assign.

Comment: Then how to filter it for a specific theme ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with the existing option for the time concern **Catalog -> Manage Categories**. Then Choose tab **Custom Design -> Custom Design** dropdown. Please create the new category attribute for custom design theme and follow the below steps,

Rewrite  the category helper block,

In `config.xml`,

```
<helpers>
   <catalog>
     <rewrite>
        <category>Namespace_Module_Helper_Category</category> 
     </rewrite>
   </catalog>
</helpers>
```

In `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/Category.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Helper_Category extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
  public function canShow($category)
    {
        if (is_int($category)) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category);
        }

        if (!$category->getId()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$category->isInRootCategoryList()) {
            return false;
        }

        $_designDatas = array('locale','layout','template','default','skin');
        $currentPackage = Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName();
        $categoryTheme = $category->getCustomDesign(); //Here use custom design attribute name
        if($categoryTheme)
        {
            $result = explode('/',$categoryTheme);
            if($result[0] ==  $currentPackage)
            {
                foreach($_designDatas as $_designData)
                {
                    $theme = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme($_designData);
                    if($theme == $result[1])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```